Pandas Pivot / Rows to Columns Join
I will always be working with < 1000 lines of data, not too concerned with data performance
The transformation will would never exceed OP#5
Please advise the best way to do this in Pandas or pure python.
I attempted to do this with dataframe.pivot_table. The issue lies in the index repeats itself, and then it will simply create rows for each CAT rather than simply sticking the 1st CAT based on the index into OP#1 and then the 2nd CAT based on the duplicate index into OP#2, etc.
Data before transform



ID
MISC
CAT
TIME




id1
123
CAT A
VALUE


id1
123
CAT B
VALUE


id1
123
CAT C
VALUE


id1
123
CAT C
VALUE


id1
123
CAT E
VALUE


id2
145
CAT A
VALUE


id2
145
CAT B
VALUE


id3
101
CAT D
VALUE


id3
101
CAT E
VALUE


id4
500
CAT D
VALUE


id5
600
CAT E
VALUE



Data after transform.



ID
MISC
OP#1
TIME
OP#2
TIME
OP#3
TIME
OP#4
TIME
OP#5
TIME




id1
123
CAT A
VALUE
CAT B
VALUE
CAT C
VALUE
CAT D
VALUE
CAT E
VALUE


id2
145
CAT A
VALUE
CAT B
VALUE








id3
101
CAT E
VALUE
CAT E
VALUE








id4
500
CAT D
VALUE










id5
600
CAT E
VALUE












Please do not use images to provide code snippet. Add the bare minimum code to the post to provide context and any errors if you encounter and also things that you have tried.

Are the rows for id1 and id3 in the result correct?

Code
out = (df.assign(cc=df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1))
       .pivot(index=['ID', 'MISC'], columns='cc')
       .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
       .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(
           x.columns.map(lambda x: f'OP#{x[1]}' if x[0] == 'CAT' else 'TIME'), 
           axis=1))
       .reset_index()
)

out


Awesome, this initially kinda works. I have not yet figured out the details of how this works, the only potential problem I see is this line  x.columns.map(lambda x: f'OP#{x[1]}' if x[0] == 'CAT' else 'TIME'). All the column headers are named TIME because 'CAT' is really short for Category for example, instead of CAT A, CAT B, CAT C its really (sawhorse, donkey, monkey, panda)
